# Convolution of two $L^\infty$ function with compact support.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convolution

I have the following lemma without proof:

> **Lemma.** Let $f, g \in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ with compact supports. Then $f \ast g \in C(\mathbb R^n)$.

Is this even true?

I get this:
$$
\begin{align*}
\vert (f \ast g)(x) - (f \ast g)(x') \vert 
&\leq \int_{\mathbb R^n} \vert f(x - y) - f(x' - y) \vert \vert g(y) \vert \, \mathrm dy \\
&\leq \Vert g \Vert_{L^\infty} \int_{\mathbb R^n} \vert f(x - y) - f(x' - y) \vert \, \mathrm dy
\end{align*}
$$

Is there a way to estimate this further?

Comment: A bounded function with compact support lies in $L^1$. The conviolution of $f\in L^1$ and $g\in L^\infty$ is continuous (hint: approximate $f$ by a continuous function with compact support.)

Comment: Actually $f*g \in C_c(\mathbb R^n).$